# circular movement around a node

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Hi I'm trying to make a SKSpriteNode run in circles around a parentNode  (another SKSpriteNode) while the parentNode is free to move around. I've tried this with using CGPath and SKAction.follow()path. However I can only seemed to the sprite to run circles around a fix location, not around another node that's moving around.

Comment: [Edit] your question with relevant code showing what you are currently doing and clearly point out where your issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a child to your moving sprite (an SKNode) with a position of (0,0).  Then add your "orbiting" sprite to that SKNode at a position of (0,radius).  Then you can run an action on the SKNode to rotate (forever) and the orbiting node will circle around your sprite wherever it moves to.